# How to use `IOConnectCallAsyncScalarMethod` with a GCD dispatch queue

Tags: macos, grand-central-dispatch, iokit, driverkit, libdispatch

I am working on some code that uses `IOConnectCallAsyncScalarMethod()` to get callbacks from a DriverKit extension. The setup is quite heavy, involving spawning a thread, manually creating a `CFMachPortRef`, adding its `CFRunLoopSourceRef` to a `CFRunLoop` and then pumping that run loop.

In order to simplify this code and reduce the risk of race conditions, I would like to get the IOKit callback on a dispatch queue instead. Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After going back and forth on this unsuccessfully, I finally found the answer in the [OS X and iOS Kernel Programming](https://books.google.dk/books?id=KjX57QfgwZkC&pg=PA95&lpg=PA95&dq=%22IOConnectCallAsyncScalarMethod%22&source=bl&ots=f1Z6YeMFR4&sig=ACfU3U2PJ_i2brpOozvVyzgt_JLNZoZ0RQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjm5qDj6sz1AhViQfEDHbQvAK4Q6AF6BAggEAM#v=onepage&q=%22IOConnectCallAsyncScalarMethod%22&f=false) book (page 95, listing 5-15).

The trick is to use a `IONotificationPortRef` along with `IONotificationPortSetDispatchQueue` to set the target dispatch queue. Then to actually have the callback dispatched to that queue, set up an `io_async_ref64_t` and use it. Here's an outline of what the code would look like:

```
// Create a notification port for IOKit service callbacks
IONotificationPortRef notificationPort = IONotificationPortCreate(kIOMasterPortDefault);
        
// Run notification callbacks on the desired dispatch queue
IONotificationPortSetDispatchQueue(self.notificationPort, dispatch_get_main_queue()); 

io_async_ref64_t asyncRef;
   
asyncRef[kIOAsyncCalloutFuncIndex] = (uint64_t)callback;
asyncRef[kIOAsyncCalloutRefconIndex] = (uint64_t)(__bridge void *)self;
    
uint32_t cmd = 0xCAFE; // Method as defined by the service
kern_return_t error = IOConnectCallAsyncScalarMethod(connection, cmd, IONotificationPortGetMachPort(notificationPort), asyncRef, kIOAsyncCalloutCount, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL);
```

`callback` should have this signature: `void commandReadyCallback(void *context, IOReturn result)`. (AKA. `IOAsyncCallback0`)

I hope this helps some poor soul in the future.

Comment: Yes, this is the correct way of going about it.